# ¿Mi navbar al cerrar no realiza la animación especificada?

Tags: javascript, html, css, libreria

Estoy haciendo una navbar para la versión de celular de mi página, pude lograr que mi navbar se abra y cierre mediante un script donde cambio el visibility de la nav de hidden a visible y viceversa para cerrar la nav. Ahora, quiero que luzca un poco mejor y tenga un efecto donde al abrirse haya una transición hacia la derecha y al cerrar haya una transición hacia la izquierda. Para esto utilizo la librería de Animate.css y puedo lograr la primer animación para abrir la navbar pero el problema está en que no puedo hacer funcionar la otra animación para cerrar, solo se cierra rápido :( dejo  el código aquí:

```js
< script >

  const nav = document.querySelector(".main__nav");
const abrir = document.querySelector("#abrir"); /*Hace referencia a una imagen para abrir la nav*/
const cerrar = document.querySelector("#cerrar"); /*Hace referencia a una 'X' para cerrar la nav*/

abrir.addEventListener("click", () => {

  nav.style.visibility = "visible";
  nav.classList.toggle("animate__fadeInLeft");
  nav.classList.remove("animate__fadeOutLeft");

})

cerrar.addEventListener("click", () => {
    nav.style.visibility = "hidden";
    nav.classList.add("animate__fadeOutLeft");
    nav.classList.remove("animate__fadeInLeft");

  })

  </script>
```

```css
.main__nav {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: start;
  position: absolute;
  gap: 1rem;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  padding: 2rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 50vmax rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main__nav container animate__animated" id="nav">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="30" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-x-lg" viewBox="0 0 16 16" id="cerrar">
          <path d="M2.146 2.854a.5.5 0 1 1 .708-.708L8 7.293l5.146-5.147a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708L8.707 8l5.147 5.146a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 8.707l-5.146 5.147a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L7.293 8 2.146 2.854Z" />
        </svg>

  <ul class="main__links">
    <li class="main__list"><a href="#" class="main__link">Home</a></li>
    <li class="main__list"><a href="#" class="main__link">Shop</a></li>
    <li class="main__list"><a href="#" class="main__link">About</a></li>
    <li class="main__list"><a href="#" class="main__link">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```